# Why can't I move your files to System folders (QuickLook MIDI files fix)

Tags: mac, quicklook

Your instructions say:
...
    Move Audio.qlgenerator to `/System/Library/QuickLook`
    Move Music.qldisplay to `System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A`

But I am unable to do so. They just "won't move." I'm running OS 10.11.6 (a recent upgrade). Have they made it so us mere mortals can mess with the guts of the OS?

TIA
KenK

Comment: Whose instructions? [they're wrong, btw - should be ...framework/Versions/A/Plugins/ but that's beside the point] Also, both those files should already exist where you're trying to move them. 3rdly, those areas are protected by System Integrity Protection [SIP] see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209441/system-library-launchagents-is-locked-in-el-capitan/209452#209452

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this was in response to to my answer to a question awhile back about a quicklook plugin I made to play back MIDI files.

Tetsujin is correct, those files are already there, and to replace them you do have to disable SIP. You're essentially overwriting a small portion of the quicklookui framework (located in the quartz.framework) to a version from past versions of OS X (10.7 specifically) to allow midi files to be played through quicklook.

Apple got rid of this functionality due to minor security risks it posed.

For me however, the minor security risk I was taking was well worth the major inconvenience of not having midi playback in quicklook and I shared my answer with others who perhaps felt the same.

But keep in mind, there is a *minor* security risk and following those instructions are at your own risk.

That said, I have tested it out/been running it on 10.11 for months now with no apparent bugs in the quicklookui framework, quartz framework, etc.

Short answer however...

1. Boot into recovery mode (Shut down and hold `command - r` once boot up process begins
2. Click Utilities at the top, and then Terminal
3. Type in `csrutil disable`
4. Reboot normally
5. You should now be able to replace the file at `System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A`

But be very careful with SIP disabled and don't tinker around with system files if you don't know what you're doing - also always be sure to have a recent back up